# Zend framework 2 - issue in Rest api

Tags: rest, zend-framework2

I nearly find the way, how to implenment the REST Style in Zend Framework 2.

But my doubt is, the methods like get(), getList() is working fine, but the update() method id not calling and showing the following error in the html page.

HTML PAGE:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Login</title>
<script src="jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){                     
      $(function(){
         $("#sb").click(function(e){

         alert("put method");
            e.preventDefault();


        $.ajax({
        type: 'PUT',
        url: 'http://128.199.233.137/api/v1/tes/74',
        data: {"gender":"1","country":"1","state":"2","city":"23","address1":"address123","address2":"address2","postal_code":"627811","birthdate":"11-12-2045","phone":"0442805565","mobile":"9865521557","blood_group":"o-","weight":"60","height":"5.2","bmi":"10"},
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function(result) {

        console.log(result);

            // Do something with the result
        }
    });


        });
      });
    });
</script>
</head>

<body>

<div  id = "sb">asdf</div>
</body>
</html>


    OPTIONS http://233.102.233.137/api/v1/tes/74 jquery-2.1.3.js:8625 jQuery.ajaxTransport.sendjquery-2.1.3.js:8161 jQuery.extend.ajaxput.html:16 (anonymous function)jquery-2.1.3.js:4430 jQuery.event.dispatchjquery-2.1.3.js:4116 jQuery.event.add.elemData.handle
put.html:1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://233.102.233.137/api/v1/tes/74. Invalid HTTP status code 405
```

MY controller is:

```
  <?php
namespace Tes\Controller;
use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractRestfulController;
use Zend\View\Model\JsonModel;
use Zend\Http\Response;

class TesController extends AbstractRestfulController
{
    //getAction
    public function get($id) { 
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT');
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With, Content-Type");
        $resp = array("method" => "Get", "id" => $id);
        return new JsonModel($resp);
    }

    //updateAction
    public function update($id, $data) { 
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT');
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With, Content-Type"); 
        $resp = array("method" => "Update", "id" => $id, "data" => $data);
        return new JsonModel($resp);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be that your server is not properly configured for handling requests other than `POST` and `GET`. Sometimes a server configuration is set to deny all other http verbs and that could be why you get a `405 - Method not allowed` response.

So the questions are:

**1:** what web server are you using?

**2:** is your server configured to handle all request verbs.

Comment: Thanks Wilt, so far i have travelling with zend means, you are also a reason..i am using apache server

Comment: Is `Invalid HTTP status code 405` all you get or is there more information available on the request in your development tools (response content). It is important to see where the response comes from (ZF2 or not).

Comment: When you try with the postman, you will get the result..http://128.199.233.137/api/v1/tes/319 try this {   
    "gender":"1",
    "country":"1",
    "state":"2",
    "city":"23",
    "address1":"27,djkfhasdkjh,kjsdfhdkjs,kjsdh",
    "address2":"ksjadh f,sdkjfhjk",
    "postal_code":"627811",
    "birthdate":"11-12-2045",
    "phone":"0442805565",
    "mobile":"9865521557",
    "blood_group":"o-",
    "weight":"60",
    "height":"5.2",
    "bmi":"10"
} with headers : Content-Type : application/json

Comment: I get 200 response. All seems fine.

Comment: The problem arises only when we are calling from the localhost, please find the client code in my question